# Notification dropdown symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

I have a notification icon. When user clicks on it, a dropdown appears and shows a list. I want to filter list to only show what's related to the connected user.

```html
{% if app.user.roles[0] == "ROLE_DEVELOPPER"%}
<!-- dropdown notification message -->
<li class="dropdown">
    <a title="Notifications" href="#fakelink" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <strong> <i class="fa fa-bell"></i></strong>

    </a>
    {% if notif_conges|length > 0 %}
    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated half flipInX">
        //this section
        {% for notif_c in notif_conges %}

        {% if  notif_c.etat == "Acceptée" %}
        <li><a>Votre demande : "{{notif_c.motif}}" Envoyée le "{{notif_c.CreatedAt|date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}" a était traitée </a></li>
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

    </ul>
    {% endif %}

</li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm not sure to understand. Do you want to display only notification of current user? If this is correct, you only have to filter notification. Your controller should call your NotificationRepository and find notification attached to current connected user.

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant yes that's what I want to do because I'm getting notifications of all users I want to get only thoses who are related to the 'id' of the current user. I didn't get what you suggested I am a begginer can you provide more details please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to filter notifications. Only notifications concerning connected users have to be displayed. You have two solutions:

**The (very) bad way: Add a test in view**

```html
    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated half flipInX">
        //this section
        {% for notif_c in notif_conges %}

        {% if  notif_c.etat == "Acceptée" and notif_c.user = app.user %}
        <li><a>Votre demande : "{{notif_c.motif}}" Envoyée le "{{notif_c.CreatedAt|date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}" a était traitée </a></li>
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

    </ul>
```

This is a bad way because you will forward all notifications to the view

**The bad way: Add a filter in your controller**

```php
class YourController
{
    public yourAction()
    {
       /** ... your code to handle notifications **/
       foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
          if ($notification->getUser()->getId() == $this->getUser()->getId)) {
             $filteredNotification[] = $notification;
          }
       }
       return $this->render('your_template_file', [
           'notif_c' => $filteredNotifications
       ]);
    }
}
```

This is still a bad way because you are retrieving all notifications from database.

**The good way: Ask only the necessaries notification to your repository**
Assuming, your notifications are retrieving with Doctrine, repository can filter data to only retrieve pertinent data.

```php
class YourController
{
    public yourAction()
    {
       /** ... your code is certainly something lke this: **/
         $notificationRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Notification');
         $notifications = $notificationRepository->findAll();
         render 

       return $this->render('your_template_file', [
           'notif_c' => $notifications
       ]);
    }
}
```

Replace `findAll()` by `findBy(array $criteria)` and add a criteria as first parameter:

```php
class YourController
{
    public yourAction()
    {
         $notificationRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Notification');
         $notifications = $notificationRepository->findBy([
           'etat' => 'Acceptée',
           'user' => $this->getUser(), //this could be a little different, I do not remember how to handle user in Sf2.8
         ]);
         render 

       return $this->render('your_template_file', [
           'notif_c' => $notifications
       ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly thanks a lot ( I tried the very bad way in fact  )! do you have any idea on how can I make the display sorted by date(attribute called CreatedAt) ?

Comment: I tried it in this function but nothing happened still shows the old in the head of the list

Answer (score 0):

Yo must use is_granted twig filter.

You can specify the user role that you one but ***IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED*** role is given to all users who are logged in.

```
{% is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') %}
<!-- dropdown notification message -->

...

{% endif %}
```